# Notepad++ folding and comments

Tags: notepad++, folding

I have recently upgraded from 5.9 to 6.8 and am mostly loving the improved flexibility of the user defined language options. However I use a proprietary language at work that has some frustrating traits.  I have managed to work around most of them but I am stuck on the last one.  We use `//` to define comments which is simple enough to rebuild in this version, but by tradition we mark regions for folding with `//.` and `//..`

I have a significant amount of code formatted like this to fold where I need it to but I haven't been able to get 6.8 to replicate the 5.9 folding functionality.

```
//==================
//. Tax Rates
//==================
DATA WORK.T_TAX_RATES;
INFILE "\\Info region(company)\Allocation Statement\taxrates.xlsx" TAB FIRSTOBS = 2;
COLUMN STARTDATE TYPE = DATE;
RUN;

//..
//============================================================================
```

I would like this code block to fold leaving just:

```
//==================
//. Tax Rates
//============================================================================
```

but in this version it only seems to recognise a folding start point followed by a `.` when parsing `//..`, let alone recognising either `//.` or `//..` when I set the comment line style to `//`.

Can anyone give me any pointers?